# Flutter, how to dispose dialog TextEditingController from another class

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I implemented dialogs in different dart files because it is too long (for clean organized)

but I just realized that TextEditingController is expensive (there are many controller in dialogs)

and since each dart files without "class" are not having "dispose" functions (which are dialogs dart file)

so I am not able to dispose

how to figure out this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**CLear your value when you close or submit the dialog box**

```
Ex : TextController firstname;

firstname.text='' or null;
```

Comment: Does it get the same effect as firstname.dispose() ?

Comment: yes I know that but I just little worry about that if it is little bit different to dispose

Comment: yes, it is different. you need to use the flutterMVC package to use dispose  method